# 4 leaved Integral Problem

Tags: calculus

Hey I have a quick question.

> Given the function
>   $$ r(\theta) = 1 - 2 \sin(3 \theta ),$$
>   what is the area of a small, and big leaf?

I've started by finding the bounds to be:

$ a=5 \pi/18, b=13 \pi/18 $
and I know I have to integrate.. maybe using the formula $$A= \int(1/2 r^2)?$$

The hint for the answers I've been given are $0.81$ for the small loop and $1.91$, 
but the closest I've gotten to is $2.96$ /:

Comment: Have you plotted the graph?

Comment: Yes, I used wolfram to get an idea of what it looks like...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area of the small leaf (the leaf in third quarter) is

> $$ A = \int_{\frac{\pi}{18} }^{\frac{5\pi}{18}}r^2(\theta) d\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = 0.1812. $$